# NavigationStack inside paged TabView is broken

Tags: ios, swiftui, horizontal-scrolling, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-navigationstack

I want to have horizontal paging with navigation bars on each page. Going with `TabView`, there is an issue in combination with `page` style when nesting NavigationStack. Let me show you an example.

The following code works but uses tabs.

```swift
var body: some View {
  TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    NavigationStack {
      List {
        Text("Page 1")
      }
      .tag(LandingPage.activity)
      .navigationTitle("Title")
    }
    .tabItem {
      Text("Tab 1")
    }
    NavigationStack {
      List {
        Text("Page 2")
      }
      .tag(LandingPage.activity)
      .navigationTitle("Title 2")
    }
    .tabItem {
      Text("Tab 2")
    }
  }.tabViewStyle(.automatic)
}
```

[image]

Now switching `tabViewStyle` to "page", it renders weird.

```swift
var body: some View {
  TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    NavigationStack {
      List {
        Text("Page 1")
      }
      .tag(LandingPage.activity)
      .navigationTitle("Title")
    }
    NavigationStack {
      List {
        Text("Page 2")
      }
      .tag(LandingPage.activity)
      .navigationTitle("Title 2")
    }
  }.tabViewStyle(.page)
}
```

[image]

Does anyone have any experience with such setup?